# How run Embedded mysql server via maven?

Tags: java, mysql, maven

Is there a way to run some lightweight MySql during maven integration tests? All I have found is [libmysqld](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/libmysqld.html), but it seems to be launched inside client application. May be there is a way or wrapper to run it as litle server? Or other ways/implementation to run lightweight Mysql server?

**Note**

There is also [mysql-je](http://mysql-je.sourceforge.net/) library, looks good but too old (2006).

Comment: I can imagine that there are reasons to use MySQL during integration tests, but what are they? Because my first question is why not use an in memory database.

Comment: Ok and what inmemory database should be used? It is a good point, but in case of different db I have different sql dialect. It is the first. The second - question is not about running entire MySql, but litgh version, which can be (in good case) inmemory of course, but support all (or most used) MySql features. (by features I mostly mean sql syntax, not all db server features)

Answer (score 2):

As @hotzst mentioned, an embedded database like [h2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) or [hsqldb](http://hsqldb.org/) would be already very helpful.

But if you really have to , you could use the https://github.com/rhuss/docker-maven-plugin to start any piece of software within your maven build process.

The only precondition would be a working docker or docker-machine installation on your machine.

I use the following code snippet to start a mongodb while doing integration test

```
<plugin>

    <groupId>org.jolokia</groupId>
    <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.13.7</version>

    <configuration>                                 
        <logDate>default</logDate>
        <autoPull>true</autoPull>
        <images>
            <image>
                <alias>mysql</alias>
                <name>mysql:5.7.10</name>
                <run>
                    <ports>
                        <port>3306:3306</port>
                    </ports>
                    <log>
                        <prefix>Mongo</prefix>
                        <color>yellow</color>
                    </log>
                </run>
            </image>
        </images>
    </configuration>

    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>start</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>build</goal>
                <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>stop</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>stop</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>

    </executions>
</plugin>
```

you can start the all integration tests and the according maven phases with `mvn:verify`.
The first time you run this plugin may take a while.

Comment: But they have different sql dialects, no?

Comment: Both databases offer *dialect compatibility* to other databases. In the internet you can easily find [further notes](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility).

Comment: Did you tried this mode? As I see it is needed to edit [too many things](http://matthewcasperson.blogspot.ru/2013/07/exporting-from-mysql-to-h2.html?m=1) in sql queries/schema.

Comment: Then you just try the docker-plugin